# cell string find and replace with mapping vector

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array 25 x 2 that contains names and codes, called 'names'. The codes are numeric. I have another cell 40 x 4 called 'data'.

One column in the cell 'data' contains a numeric code that can be linked to the other 'names' cell. What I was trying to do is replace the numeric codes in 'data' with the corresponding name from the 'names' cell.

I was looking at converting the numeric code field to a string, line below. Then use the strrep function I believe I would have to create a loop to replace all the strings. Is there a better way of doing this task? Is a loop required?

```
 num2str(cell2mat(data(:,1)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `ismember`, however `ismember` won't work on a cell array of numbers hence I have used `cell2mat` to convert them to numeric vectors first.

```
names = {'A', 1; 'B', 2; 'C', 3};
data = {1, 1, 'a'; 2, 2, 'b'; 1, 1, 'c'; 1, 1, 'd'; 3, 3, 'e'};

[~, ind] = ismember(cell2mat(data(:,1)), cell2mat(names(:,2)))
data(:,1) = names(ind)
```

You can actually make use of comma separated lists to get rid of the `cell2mat`calls as follows:

```
[~, ind] = ismember([data{:,1}], [names{:,2}])
```